# Php ad rotator(shuffle) errors

Tags: javascript, php

Hello im using ad rotator dor my website to show different ads per refresh homeeber some ad codes dont work and give php errors. How can i fix that? Getting errors on key,format,height,width,params and document write section. Error is T_STRING unexpected

````
<?php
$advert = array();

$advert[] = '<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : '123456789',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 90,
        'width' : 728,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.website/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>';

shuffle($advert);
echo $advert[0];
?>```
````

Comment: If you are using adrotate on a wordpress install, it has that option without your custom code.

Comment: Thanks but im not using wordpress

Comment: Bad practices. Stay away from `document.write`. Also, once a JavaScript script tag is cached it comes from the memory. I would do something more like:

    `<?php
    $o = new StdClass; $o->prop1 = 'value 1';
    $a = ['key'=>'123456789', 'format'=>'iframe', 'height'=>90, 'width'=>728, 'params'=>$o];
    $keys = array_keys($a); shuffle($keys);
    foreach($keys as $k){
      $r[k] = $a[$k];
    }
    echo json_encode($r);
    ?>`

That just gives you a JavaScript Object, so you would need to use AJAX or do like `const resultArray = /* put the above code here */;`

Answer (score -1):

In your code you're creating a single-quoted string containing your Javascript and assigning it to a PHP array element.

However, your string contains single quotes in a variety of places, so PHP sees a jumble of quoted and unquoted strings which it can't make sense of.

Change the code to use [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax:

```
<?php
$advert = array();

$advert[] = <<<EOT     // <<< is the HEREDOC preamble. EOT is the delimiter
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : '123456789',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 90,
        'width' : 728,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.website/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>

EOT;           // EOT delimiter marks the end of the string

shuffle($advert);
echo $advert[0];
?>
```